# Python Postgres query with transaction block over single connection

Tags: python, postgresql, newline, greenplum

Currently I have two separate statements being passed through to Postgres (Greenplum).
1. Truncates a table 
2. loads data using \copy

```
myStr="export PGPASSWORD=" + dbPass + "; psql -h " + dbHost + " -p " + dbPort + " -d " + dbName + " -U " + dbUser + " -c " + "\"" + "truncate table " + dbTable + ";\""
print(myStr)
subprocess.call(myStr,shell=True)
myStr="export PGPASSWORD=" + dbPass + "; psql -h " + dbHost + " -p " + dbPort + " -d " + dbName + " -U " + dbUser + " -c " + "\"" + "\\" + "copy " + dbTable + " from " + "'" + csvfile + "' with " + copyOpts + ";" + "select count(*) from " + dbTable + ";\""
print(myStr)
subprocess.call(myStr,shell=True)
```

Sometimes the load has errors but the truncate already happened, so I'm trying to run the two statements in one connection so I can put a transcation block (BEGIN ... COMMIT;) that way if the data load fails it will rollback to before the truncate happens.

I tried the below method:

```
myStr="export PGPASSWORD=" + dbPass + "; psql -h " + dbHost + " -p " + dbPort + " -d " + dbName + " -U " + dbUser + " -c " + "\"" + "truncate table " + dbTable + ";" + " \\" + "copy " + dbTable + " from " + "'" + csvfile + "' with " + copyOpts + ";" + "select count(*) from " + dbTable + ";\""
print(myStr)
```

Which resolves to the command:

```
export PGPASSWORD=abcde; 
psql -h abcde.testserver.corp 
-p 5432 -d namem -U username -c 
"truncate table schema.example; 
\copy schema.example from 
'/home/testing/schema/schema.example_export.csv' 
with header null as '' escape 'off' delimiter E',' ;
select count(*) from schema.example;"
```

However I am getting the error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"

I believe this is due to the `\` commands have to be on a separate line.

Is there a way to split the command into separate lines so I can execute ll the commands in a single connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't separate backslash commands from other commands if you are using the `-c` option. You can send your commands via `STDIN` to `psql` using `echo`:

```
export PGPASSWORD=abcde;
echo "truncate table schema.example; 
\copy schema.example from '/home/testing/schema/schema.example_export.csv' with header null as '' escape 'off' delimiter E',' ;
select count(*) from schema.example;" | psql -h abcde.testserver.corp -p 5432 -d namem -U username
```

That's a little bit clumsy. It's better to use `subprocess.Popen`

```
theCommand = """truncate table schema.example; 
\copy schema.example from 
'/home/testing/schema/schema.example_export.csv' 
with header null as '' escape 'off' delimiter E',' ;
select count(*) from schema.example;"""
theProcess = subprocess.Popen("psql -h abcde.testserver.corp -p 5432 -d namem -U username", 
    stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
theOutput, theErrors = theProcess.communicate(input = theCommand)
```

But the best way should be avoiding shell commands and using a database adaptor like PyGreSQL.

Comment: Another option, and maybe easier, is to use the SQL COPY command, instead of the \copy from psql. \copy is really just a wrapper around COPY.

Comment: Confirmed working using the first echo method piping the commands through. The end statement looks like this:
 myStr="export PGPASSWORD=" + dbPass + "; echo \"" + "truncate table " + dbTable + ";" + " \\" + "copy " + dbTable + " from " + "'" + csvfile + "' with " + copyOpts + ";" + "select count(*) from " + dbTable + ";\"" + " | psql -h " + dbHost + " -p " + dbPort + " -d " + dbName + " -U " + dbUser